# Mailgun: Email Forward not Working?

Tags: mailgun, email, namecheap

I'm using Mailgun in an app I'm developing. Sending email works fine and now I'm trying to set it up to receive incoming email.

I set things up per the Mailgun docs, for catch-all auto-forwarding to my usual email address. I then sent a test email to myName@myDomain.app. (It's a .app domain name).

The email didn't bounce, but it didn't arrive at the forward to address either.

Here's how I have the MX records set up on NameCheap:

[image: MX record setup on Namecheap for Mailgun]

Here's how I have the route set up on Mailgun:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to forward  email to another email  via mailgun:

1- Click “Create Route.” In the form that follows:

2- Select “Match Recipient” as the “Expression Type.”

3- Set the “Recipient” as the email address you want others to send mail to (e.g., “info@example.com”).

4- Under “Actions,” check the box next to “Forward,” and enter your personal Gmail address (e.g., “info@gmail.com”).

5- Set a low “Priority,” such as 1.

6- click “Create Route.” Emails addressed to “info@example.com” will now be forwarded to “info@gmail.com.”

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same problem, so I'm answering in case it helps anyone else.

Mailgun is focused on sending, so they recommend that you use a subdomain (e.g, mg.mydomain.com), but this won't work when using Mailgun to **forward incoming email** (unless it's sent to somebody@mg.mydomain.com, which is probably not what you want).

For incoming mail forwarding you must use your root domain in Mailgun. In other words, in your DNS MX records (and in your TXT record for SPF) you need to use "@" for the root instead of "mg" for a subdomain. And don't put "mg." in front of the domain you add in Mailgun.

There's nothing wrong with the CatchAll() route. That's working for me. Although you have to forward to a single destination email, not @mydomain.com or *@mydomain.com.

And to be clear, the "Test your route" section only tests the rules. It doesn't actually send out a test email.

Comment: Does this require a paid mailgun plan?